# How to make imageview with different shape in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, shapes

[image]

I want to change the normal ios imageview to this below image shape(Like arc)

Comment: use bezierpath...follow this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1

Comment: Thank you if you give separate code  means really help

Comment: Hi Lydia is that a imageView and you want to crop it like the shown image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this to design the shape as per your requirement, you can add extra lines to the path incase you need to modify the bezier path. Create a custom UIImageView class and subclass the image view in storyboard to your custom class.

```
import UIKit

class customImageView: UIImageView {


    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    //    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    //    {
    //
    //
    //    }


    override func setNeedsLayout() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height/2))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 0))
        path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2), radius: self.frame.size.width/2, startAngle:-CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), clockwise: false)

        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height))
        path.closePath()
        UIColor.redColor().setFill()
        path.stroke()
        path.bezierPathByReversingPath()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }

}
```

If you want to add the image through code kindly use it like this

```
 func shapeImage()
    {
        let customImgView = customImageView()
        customImgView.image = UIImage(named: "Image")
        customImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)

        self.view.addSubview(customImgView)
    }
```

This is the actual image on left hand side and the image after shaping as per your requirement in the simulator on the right hand side

[image]

Comment: Really thank you.This is i want .And i did not use storay board, so can you please tell me how to add the imageview subclass to main viewcontroller.

Comment: Create a object of CustomImageView , set the frame and  your desired image to it and then add it to your view controller

Comment: var custom = Customimageview()  next line var imgview = myimgeframe next line imgeview = custom.IS this right

Comment: Yes and add  your image and the frame you want to and add it to the view controller

Comment: i have edited the answer kindly check the shapeImage function

Comment: Please check my edited question.I want to add three imageview as a circle.One image you i did, and please let me know other two.

Comment: How would I do this in swift3 @OmkarGuhilot.

Comment: @Lydia how would I do this in swift 3

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot I have used Your Code, I have Created one ImageView In storyboard and provide class as customImageView,  but it won't Work.  Can you please Help Me?

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot If I create ImageView Programatically then it works Perfectly but I need to use it using StoryBoard Please Help.!

Comment: @KhushbuDesai the above solution mentioned is as per storyboard. Have you mentioned your subclass for the ImageView in storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I had mentioned it

Comment: is your setNeedsLayout getting called?