# How to convert image view to custom shape (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, imageview, cashapelayer

I am trying to convert the a single imageview to output in the in the object on the right. This is a very similar question to [How to make imageview with different shape in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163317/how-to-make-imageview-with-different-shape-in-swift). However that was in swift2. I tried it and it does not seem to work in swift3.

[image: ll]

Comment: Please show us the code you tried. There really is no difference whatsoever for this (except some syntax) between Swift 2 and Swift 3. None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func addMask(_ bezierPath: UIBezierPath) {
        let pathMask = CAShapeLayer()
        pathMask.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = pathMask
    }
}
```

---

Testing playground:

```
let myPicture = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
let iv = UIImageView(image: myPicture)

let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.move(to: iv.center)
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: iv.frame.maxX, y: 0))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: iv.frame.maxX, y: iv.frame.maxY))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: iv.frame.maxY))
bezierPath.addLine(to: .zero)
bezierPath.close()

iv.addMask(bezierPath)
```

Comment: Do i put the testing playground in the extension file?

Comment: You need to add the extension in your playground file before the test code

Comment: In your project you can add a new swift file, add the import UIKit to the file and add the extension there,

Comment: I can't thank you enough for you help. I am curious how I can change the shape. Right now the image is cropped. I would like to just change the shape of the image. So all of the image is just transformed into another shape. Thank You.

Comment: @LeoDabus . This helped me a lot . i have one doubt can u clarify me

Comment: @UmaMadhavi fell feee to open a new question and post the link here once you finish it

Comment: @LeoDabus . I want exactly this kind of image https://i.stack.imgur.com/veZRT.png . Please help me